# Python string index

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7

I have a file which contains users:

```
Sep 15 04:34:31 li146-252 sshd[13326]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42579 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:33 li146-252 sshd[13328]: Failed password for invalid user romero from 212.58.111.170 port 42715 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:36 li146-252 sshd[13330]: Failed password for invalid user rom from 212.58.111.170 port 42838 ssh2
```

Trying to use index method for string to print the users from the file, which is not working:

```
with open ('test.txt') as file: 
        for line in file.readlines(): 
                lines = line.split() 
                string = ' '.join(lines)
                print string.index('user')+1
```

Comment: It does exactly what I'd expect it to do, define "not working".

Comment: `print lines.index('user')+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print all the user names which exists just after to the string `user` .

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        print(words[words.index('user')+1])
```

Comment: If you for example have one line and want to change the username in the text file is that possible ?

Comment: sorry , i don't know what you mean.. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

This will print out the user names contained in the file. It assumes that the user name is always the word following the first instance of "user" in the line. Care is taken to handle any lines that do not contain the word "user", or that have "user" as the last word in the line.

```
keyword = 'user'
with open ('test.txt') as f: 
    for line in f.readlines(): 
        words = line.split()
        try:
            index_user = words.index(keyword) + 1
            print words[index_user]
        except ValueError:
            pass    # line does not contain keyword
        except IndexError:
            pass    # keyword is the last word in the line
```

Answer (score 0):

What this does:

1. Look at each line in the file
2. Split that line into a list of item  based on the white space in the original string version of that line
3. Search the newly created list item for `user` and memorize at what index it found user.
4. Add 1 to the index at which user was found and print that item

---

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.split(' ')  # convert the string to a list
        print(line[line.index('user')+1])  # find 'user' in the list and print the item that comes after that
```

---

Instead of `print(line[10])` you could just do `print(line[10])`. This assume that the name will be at the same spot though. I would do it this way.

---

Additionally if you want to change the names in your log, here is how.

```
file = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
new_file = []
for line in file.readlines():  # read the lines
    line = (line.split(' '))
    line[10] = 'vader'  # edit the name
    new_file.append(' '.join(line))  # store the changes to a variable

file = open('tmp.txt', 'w')  # write the new log to file
[file.writelines(line) for line in new_file]
```

Comment: What if you want to change the user with a variable you have in a variable in your script?

Comment: Yeah, for example. Is that possible?